# I want to rewrite subdomains and folders to params

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory

I like to rewrite my subdomain site (wildcard) and when exists folders to params for the index.php file.

So

www.domain.com
www.domain.com/js/file.js
www.domain.com/css/file.css
www.domain.com/images/file.jpg
**should be preserved!**

And these should change to parameters for index.php

sub.domain.com/
to
www.domain.com/index.php?key1=sub

sub.domain.com/2015
to
www.domain.com/index.php?key1=sub&key2=2015

sub.domain.com/2015/12
to
www.domain.com/index.php?key1=sub&key2=2015&key3=12

Is this possible?

What I have sofar is 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1?page=%1 [QSA,L,NE]`

Thank you very much!

So I rewritten some of @anubhava his htaccess to this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.gebruikmaar\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1?page=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.gebruikmaar\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/][0-9]*)(/?)$ $1?page=%1&key2=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.gebruikmaar\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/][0-9]*)/([^/][0-9]*)(/?)$ $1?page=%1&key2=$1&key3=$2 [QSA,L]
```

And it almost works!

This url: 
    http://agenda.gebruikmaar.nl
Becomes
    http://www.gebruikmaar.nl/index.php?page=agenda


BUT :-(
This url: 
    http://agenda.gebruikmaar.nl/2015
Becomes: 
    http://www.gebruikmaar.nl/index.php?page=agenda&key1=201

So where's the last character (5) at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?key1=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?key1=%1&key2=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?key1=%1&key2=$1&key3=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not getting any GET back what so ever.

Comment: It's in the document root, yes. And no other rules. The url i'm going to is -> http://agenda.gebruikmaar.nl/2015/ (not live yet, it's on my vagrant environment) and should send the 2 params : agenda and 2015 to the index.php file.

Comment: When using your precise code it says: The requested URL /2015/ was not found on this server. :-)

Comment: And going to http://agenda.gebruikmaar.nl/ it does not pass the agenda param to the index.php ($_REQUEST is empty)

Comment: (yes changed domain\.com to gebruikmaar\.nl :-) )